# Weird beta inflated distribution qq plot (easy reproducible code included)

Tags: beta-distribution, zero-inflation

First, I do this

```
library(gamlss)
simnorm <- rnorm(1000, 0.5,0.1)
simzero <- rep(0,1000)

x <- sample(c(simnorm,simzero),1000, replace = TRUE)
```

which gives me data in the $[0,1)$ interval.

Then, I wish to fit a zero-inflated beta distribution. This is incorporated in the gamlss package, so one can go ahead and do this:

```
model1 <- gamlss(x ~ 1, family = BEZI)
model2 <- gamlss(x ~1, family = BEINF0)
```

as both BEZI and BEINF0 are apparently zero-inflated beta distributions. But then, when we do model diagnostics, model2 has the qqnorm plot

[image]

and model1 has the qqnorm plot

[image]

This would seem to suggest that model1 is terrible, while model2 is a fantastic fit.

But, what's the difference between the assumptions underlying each model? They both seem to be the same, as far as I can tell?